# /home/web/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:152:in `getaddrinfo': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to provide development environment for developers with the tech-stack ROR, postgres, redis, mongo. The `docker-compose build` is running successfully but when I ran `docker-compose up` following error was encountered.

```
web_1   | => Booting Thin
web_1   | => Rails 4.2.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
web_1   | => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
web_1   | => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
web_1   | Exiting
web_1   | /home/web/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:152:in `getaddrinfo': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
web_1   |   from /home/web/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:152:in `connect'
web_1   |   from /home/web/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:211:in `connect'
web_1   |   from /home/web/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:322:in `establish_connection'
web_1   |   from /home/web/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:94:in `block in connect'
web_1   |   from /home/web/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:279:in `with_reconnect'
```

> Following is the Dockerfile

```
# Base image.
FROM atlashealth/ruby:2.2.1

# System dependencies for gems.
#RUN apt-get update
#RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libmysqlclient-dev
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev 

# Add 'web' user which will run the application.
RUN adduser web --home /home/web --shell /bin/bash --disabled-password --gecos ""

# Add directory where all application code will live and own it by the web user.
RUN mkdir /app
RUN chown -R web:web /app

# Install gems separately here to take advantage of container caching of `bundle install`.
# Also, ensure that gems are installed as the web user and not system-wide so that we can run
# `fig web bundle install` and the web user will have permissions to update the shared Gemfile.lock.
ADD Gemfile /app/
ADD Gemfile.lock /app/
RUN chown -R web:web /app
USER web
ENV HOME /home/web
ENV PATH $PATH:/home/web/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin
ENV GEM_HOME /home/web/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
ENV GEM_PATH $GEM_HOME
RUN gem install --user-install bundler
WORKDIR /app/
RUN bundle install
USER root

# Add the whole application source to the image and own it all by web:web.
# Note: this is overwritten in development because fig mounts a shared volume at /app.
ADD . /app/
RUN chown -R web:web /app

# Clean up APT and /tmp when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Default command to run when this container is run.
USER web
WORKDIR /app/
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server"]
```

> docker-compose.yml

```
db:  
  image: postgres
  ports:
    - "5432"

redis:  
  image: redis
  ports:
    - "6379"

sidekiq:  
  build: .
  command: bundle exec sidekiq
  links:
    - db
    - redis

web:  
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
    - redis
```

I have setup the environment variable for postgres and redis host and port according to the output of `docker-compose run web env` command.

output of command `docker-compose run web cat /etc/hosts`

```
Starting xyz_db_1...
Starting xyz_redis_1...
172.17.0.32 2b231a706e7b
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.31 redis 799b65ac89cd xyz_redis_1
172.17.0.31 redis_1 799b65ac89cd xyz_redis_1
172.17.0.30 db 0bd898e19822 xyz_db_1
172.17.0.30 db_1 0bd898e19822 xyz_db_1
172.17.0.30 xyz_db_1 0bd898e19822
172.17.0.31 xyz_redis_1 799b65ac89cd
```

> config/sidekiq.yml

```
concurrency: 25
pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
queues:
  - default
  - [priority, 2]
daemon: true
```

> config/app-config.yml

```
default: &default
  redis_host: <%= ENV['XYZ_REDIS_1_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR'] %>
  redis_port: <%= ENV ['XYZ_REDIS_1_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT'] %>
  redis_namespace: 'RAILS_CACHE'

development:
  <<: *default
  redis_host: <%= ENV['XYZ_REDIS_1_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR'] %>
  redis_port: <%= ENV['XYZ_REDIS_1_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT'] %>
```

> config/initializers/redis.rb

```
# global variable to access Redis cache
# Requirement: Redis server should be up and running
# at below specified host and port
$redis = Redis.new(
  :host => APP_CONFIG["redis_host"],
  :port => APP_CONFIG["redis_port"]
)
```

Comment: It's hard to say what's happening here without knowing more about the application.  I'd suggest: don't use the environment variables, use the hostnames provided by /etc/hosts (`docker-compose run web cat /etc/hosts` to check them out).   Ex: just use `redis` not `redis_1`. I think I remember there being an issue with ruby and hostnames with underscores.

Comment: @dnephin, see the edits. I have added the output of 'docker-compose run web cat /etc/hosts'

Comment: Excuse me if I'm misunderstanding, but this looks like your app redis isn't configured correctly. Are you using redis gem all by itself, or you using a library like sidekiq/activejob?

Comment: @Anti-Fun using redis gem and sidekiq

Comment: @AjeetKhan under `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` you can configure redis hostname, so try doing something like this:

`Sidekiq.configure_server do |config| config.redis = { url: 'redis://172.17.0.31:6379' } end`

You can create a redis configuration file as well, you might have more luck setting that @ `config/initializers/redis.rb`, `$redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)`

If this makes a difference in the error, this might indicate I'm on the right track, and I'll write a proper answer...

Comment: @Anti-Fun, I did that but still, the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The `REDIS_URL` environment variable can be used to pass the Redis url to both Sidekiq and the Redis gem.

This environment variable can be set in the `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
db:  
  image: postgres
  ports:
    - "5432"

redis:  
  image: redis
  ports:
    - "6379"

web:  
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
    - redis
  environment:
    REDIS_URL: "redis://redis:6379"
```

As Sidekiq and Redis gems will use `REDIS_URL` by default, you also need to make sure that you are not overriding this default behavior in your config files. You don't need the file `config/initializers/redis.rb` anymore, and your `config/app-config.yml` should contain only your namespace:

```
default: &default
  redis_namespace: 'RAILS_CACHE'

development:
  <<: *default
```

Comment: Do you have some config or initializer files that are overriding the configuration of `Sidekiq` ou `Redis`? That would explain why the `REDIS_URL` variable is overridden.

Comment: Please see the edits to see configuration for redis and sidekiq.

Comment: `config/app-config.yml` and `config/initializers/redis.rb` are probably interfering. Your `Redis.new(:host, :post)` is overriding the configuration, so you app won't use the `REDIS_URL` environment variable. If you remove this host / port configuration, in these config files, everything should work fine.

Comment: I am using the environment variable generated by docker itself in these configuration files. Than why it is showing this issue?

Comment: Maybe the extra space between `ENV` and `['IMLIBACKEND_REDIS_1_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT']` in `app-config.yml` ?

Comment: tried doing both way, removing extra space and removing the configuration for redis in app-config.yml and redis.rb as suggested by you. Now getting the follwoing error
/myapp/app/utils/common_module/v1/cache.rb:17:in `write': undefined method `set' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: like, you say in your answer to remove the sidekiq.rb that could be under initializers, and they will the reds container will catch and pass the REDIS_URL ?